# OpenAuth2 ProviderName returns empty

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

Recentlly, I have changed default asp.net external login to OpenAuth2 for google login.
after successful login, ProviderName name is coming as empty in below method under the page RegisterExternalLogin.cs

```
 private void ProcessProviderResult()
    {
        // Process the result from an auth provider in the request
        ProviderName = OpenAuth.GetProviderNameFromCurrentRequest();
```

Comment: Hello Dont know how you are accessing for better understanding please refer followning link http://www.widecodes.com/7HHiVPkePV/login-using-goolge-oauth-20-with-c.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply webruster. before test this code, just to check,  will that code work with Auth 2.0 version of google api? Generally, it ll redirects to OpenID  API is migrated page.

Comment: Yes, My dear.. I have implemented it in my project .. its working fine. thats the reason i have suggested you

Comment: What do u mean by "OpenID API is migrated page" ??

Comment: Superb buddy. It works great. but only thing is order of the class creation should be at the top . for beginners, it ll take some time to understand.

Comment: btw, how can I integrate with membership of default asp.net? in sense, when ever we are logging in newly, it should automatically create profiles in aspnetmembership tables.

Comment: Please mark this as answer ..It will be help full to other community members also!!

Comment: Webruster, still, providername is coming as empty string. current selected provider is not getting stored under Request[ProviderNameKey].

Comment: post ur code,which u tried,with oauth key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Dont know how you are accessing for better understanding please refer followning link [Here](http://www.widecodes.com/7HHiVPkePV/login-using-goolge-oauth-20-with-c.html)